# How to call multiple onclick function from child to parent in react js

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ChildComponent from './component/childComponent';
class ParentComponent extends React.Component{
 constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {
   isShowLastScrn:false
  }
 }
 render(){
  return (
   <div className="App">
    <childComponent />
   </div>
  );
 }
}
export default ParentComponent;

import React from 'react';
import './childComponent.css'; 
class ChildComponent extends React.Component{
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
   unattempt:0,
  }
 }
 render(){
  return(
  <div className='wrapper'>
   <button type="button" className="btn" onClick={this.props.clickYestBtn}>Yes</button>
   <button type="button" className="btn" onClick={this.props.clickNoBtn}>No</button>
  </div>
 );
 }
}
export default ChildComponent;
```

I am having two buttons on child component. Both buttons have separate click event. How to pass this function from child component to parent component in react js.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check prop drilling

Answer (score 0):

Create a reference of child in parent and then you can call easily.

Answer (score 0):

this should work.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import ChildComponent from './component/childComponent';
    class ParentComponent extends React.Component{
        constructor(){
            super();
            this.state = {
                isShowLastScrn:false
            }
        }
        clickYestBtn=()=>
        {
        }
clickNoBtn=()=>
        {
        }
        render(){
            return (
                <div className="App">
                    <childComponent clickYestBtn={this.clickYestBtn} clickNoBtn={this.clickNoBtn}/>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    export default ParentComponent;

    import React from 'react';
    import './childComponent.css'; 
    class ChildComponent extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state={
                unattempt:0,
            }
        }
        render(){
            return(
            <div className='wrapper'>
                <button type="button" className="btn" onClick={this.props.clickYestBtn}>Yes</button>
                <button type="button" className="btn" onClick={this.props.clickNoBtn}>No</button>
            </div>
        );
        }
    }
    export default ChildComponent;
```